# "Enable Buffering" option in the App Options tab of the virtual directory property settings

Tags: properties, iis-7, buffering

I have some problems with MS Office SOAP toolkit and it says in the documentation that:

Soap will not work correctly unless the "Enable Buffering" option is set in the App Options tab of the virtual directory property settings.

But how do you enable it? I have a site under IIS7 and I can't find such option. I believe that when this documentation was written there was no IIS7. So does anybody know where the buffering can be switched on?
My web site is on ASP.NET .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you need it in IIS7, but you can set it like so:

> Enable or disable buffering To enable
>   or disable buffering of ASP
>   application output, use the following
>   syntax:
>
> appcmd set config /section:asp
>   /bufferingOn:True|False
>
> True enables buffering whereas False
>   disables buffering. The default value
>   is True.

Found on this [URL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730855%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: that's for ASP, but my app is on ASP.NET. Forgot to mention :) .

Comment: Unless you are in classic ASP then I am not sure it needs to be enabled.  Are you actually running into issues, or just preempting based on the documentation?